# What does it mean for a group to be free in a variety of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

I'm reading the paper *"Finitely generated cyclic extensions
of free groups are residually finite"* by Baumslag. One of the hypotheses of the main proposition in the paper is that for a group $G$ and $N < G$ a subgroup, $N$ is free in a nilpotent variety $\mathcal{V}$ of prime exponent $p$.

I understand that a variety of groups, roughly speaking, is a collection $\mathcal{V}$  of groups defined by some equation. It is nilpotent if every group in $\mathcal{V}$ is nilpotent, and has exponent $p$ if every group in $\mathcal{V}$ has exponent $p$.

What I don't understand is what Baumslag means by the fact that $N$ is free in $\mathcal{V}$? The source of my confusion lies in what comes next, mainly that the group $N$ is assumed to be a free group. Surely if $N$ is free, then it can never be contained in a variety of exponent $p$?

Comment: I don't have the paper to hand, but I would guess that when he says that $N$ is free, he means that it is  free in the variety under consideration.

Comment: Yes, I see now that the main proposition proves residual finiteness for (free-in-a-nilpotent-variety-of-prime-exponent)-by-cyclic groups, and then lifts that to free-by-cyclic groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A group $N$ is free in the variety $\mathcal{V}$ if and only if there exists a subset $X$ of $N$ such that:

1. $N\in\mathcal{V}$; and
2. $\langle X\rangle = N$; and
3. For every $G\in\mathcal{V}$ and every set-theoretic map $f\colon X\to G$, there exists a unique group homomorphism $\phi\colon N\to G$ such that $\phi|_X = f$.

In other words, $N$ is in $\mathcal{V}$ and satisfies the universal property of "free group on $X$", but relative only to groups in $\mathcal{V}$.  Sometimes we say that $N$ is "relatively free" in $\mathcal{V}$ (and the usual free groups are said to be "absolutely free").

It is not hard to show  that  $N$ is free in $\mathcal{V}$ if and only if there exists an absolutely free group $F$ such that $N\cong F/\mathcal{V}(F)$, where $\mathcal{V}(F)$ is the verbal subgroup of $F$ corresponding to $\mathcal{V}$: the smallest normal subgroup of $F$ such that the quotient lies in $\mathcal{V}$.

The canonical place to learn about varieties is Hanna Neumann's *Varieties of Groups*, Springer-Verlag, 1967, [MR 0215899](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=MR&s1=215899).